# display content based on multiple days and time of day

Tags: channel, date, time

I've seen answers on display content on a specific day, but I'm trying to figure out showing content for Multiple days. I have doctors office that wants to show it's hours Monday-friday and weekend hours. If they are not open they want it to say closed. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I'm basically just trying to figure out the most graceful way to code it. I understand that it can be done with multiple conditionals just wondering if I'm missing an obvious way to do more simply.

Comment: Javascript solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36900482/javascript-store-opening-hours

Answer (score 0):

So {current_time format="%l"} yields the current day. Can't you use a conditional based on that?

https://expressionengine.com/forums/archive/topic/195111/help-with-conditional-statement-based-on-current-day-of-the-week

Something like:

```
{if '{current_time format='%l'}' == "Saturday" OR '{current_time format='%l'}' == "Sunday"}
  CLOSED
{if:else}
  OPEN
{/if}
```

Comment: This is kind of what I was thinking but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing it. For each of the daily conditionals I'd have to add a second condition of time between 830-430.

Comment: Not for every single day. You are really just dealing with weekend (Sat/Sun) or NOT weekend (the else).  Then write a conditional that checks if current time is greater than opening and less than closing, the it's "open".

More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228346/conditional-based-on-time